# How do you find the kernel of this linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider the function $T$: $\mathcal P_2$ $\to$ $\mathcal P_2$ defined by $T(p(x))$ = $x^2$$p''(x)$, where $p''(x)$ is the second order derivative of $p(x)$.

Find the kernel of $T$.

Comment: Is $\mathcal{P}_2$ the space of all polynomials with degree at the most equal to $2$?

Comment: @ManuelNorman Yes, correct.

Comment: Hint: consider what this transformation does to each of the basis vectors of $\mathcal{P}_2$, which are $\{1, x, x^2\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write:
$$p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$$
with $a,b,c$ is some field, say, for instance, $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. Then, we have:
$$ p''(x)= 2a $$
Consequenlty, we obtain:
$$ T(p(x))= 2a x^2 $$
If $a \neq 0$, that is, $\deg p(x)=2$, then we have no solutions, because we do not have the zero polynomial. If instead $a=0$, that is, we have $0 \leq \deg p(x) \leq 1$, then we always have $T(p(x))=0$. Thus, we can conclude that:
$$ \ker T= \mathcal{P}_1 $$